# 404 with Jersey test

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, jersey

My REST class:

```
@Path("/Root")
public class REST{
 @GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String testClass() {
    return "Jersey Test";
}
.....etc}
```

My jersey test:

```
public class Test extends JerseyTest {
@Override
protected  AppDescriptor configure(){
    System.out.println("Here");
    return (new WebAppDescriptor.Builder(REST.class.getPackage().getName())
            .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "application-context-prm-test.xml").build());
}

@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
}
@Test
public void testGet(){
    WebResource webResource = client().resource("http://localhost:9998/Root/test");
    String actual = webResource.getRequestBuilder().get(String.class);
    System.out.println(actual);
}
```

I always seem to get a 404 and I've been stuck with this for four hours now. What am I missing?

Thanks SO MUCH!

Comment: My web.xml: <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <!--<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>-->
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Why do you have an edited out url-pattern?

I think the issue is, your REST is private, when jersey runs it annotation processing I'm decently sure, you need to make the route class public.

also your mapping should look like

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: sorry the REST class isnt private.

Comment: and my web.xml has : <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> sorry for the confusion

Comment: Your REST class is private, you declare it as

class REST{
...
}

The default visibility is PRIVATE

Comment: changed it to public, no change in the 404.

Comment: add your application name then root like this http://localhost:9998/applicationName/Root/test

Comment: when i deploy it as a tomcat application, this URL works fine : http://localhost:8080/Root/test

Comment: So, Do i really have to deploy it under the application name just for a test?

Comment: old thread, but i wonder: you say you can call your application at localhost:8080/Root/test but your test requests http://localhost:9998/Root/test. you should change the port.